# How can i debug a simple java file in AWS Cloud9?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, cloud9

I have to debug a simple java file, i set the breakpoint, tap the bug icon and run but it doesn’t stop on breakpoint and only run the file.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
Recently they added Enhanced support for Java SE 11. There is many specifics though. This is the URL with the documentation about the "Enhanced support for Java development" : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/enhanced-java.html

Original Answer:
Cloud9 doesn't support debug for all languages. Java debugging is not supported. Here is a full list with languages support level in Cloud9:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/language-support.html